# iOS: Get all dates in current week

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get all dates in the current week of a given date:

In the example below, the input is

> 2015-11-29 23:40:37 +0000

, so I would expect the output to be an array of dates from November 23 - November 29, but the actual output is November 30 - December 6.

```
-(NSArray *)datesForWeekOf : (NSDate *) date {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *startOfWeek;
    NSDate *endOfWeek;
    NSTimeInterval interval;

    [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth startDate:&startOfWeek interval:&interval forDate:date];
    endOfWeek = [startOfWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval-1];

    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *days = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    NSInteger dayCount = 0;
    NSMutableArray *allDates = [NSMutableArray array];

    while ( TRUE ) {
        [days setDay: ++dayCount];
        NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateByAddingComponents: days toDate: startOfWeek options: 0];
        [allDates addObject:date];
        if ( [date compare: endOfWeek] == NSOrderedDescending )
            break;

    }
    return allDates;

}
```

Comment: You are not setting the timezone.  So how could you expect an array of dates from November 23 - November 29?

Comment: I usually set the timezone in NSDateFormatter. How do I do it here ?

Comment: @ElTomato You don't need to set the timezone unless you specifically want to deal with a timezone separate from the user's current timezone.

Comment: The example time you are starting with is a tough example. Depending on where you live, `2015-11-29 23:40:37 +0000` could represent November 29 or November 30 local time. And again, where you live, the week can start on a Sunday or a Monday. If your week starts on Mondays and ends on Sundays, and `2015-11-29 23:40:37 +0000` is really November 30 in your local time, then getting the results of "November 30 - December 6" is actually correct.

Comment: @rmaddy I am in the Pacific Time Zone (GMT-8) and the week is from Monday to Sunday

Comment: Your calculations for `startOfWeek` and `endOfWeek` are fine. The problem starts with using `++dayCount` instead of `dayCount++`.

Comment: Check your calendar and time zone on device/simulator, print them from inside the app. The code is fine, as @rmaddy said.

Comment: @paiv The code is only half right. It's the loop that is wrong.

Comment: @paiv: The printed value of timeZone is `America/Vancouver (PST) offset -28800` and Calendar is `<_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper: 0x1339a3440>`

Comment: @rmaddy Just before entering the loop, the value of startOfWeek is: `2015-11-29 08:00:00 +0000` and endOfWeek is `2015-12-06 07:59:59 +0000`

Comment: And those are correct. The week starts at midnight on the 29th local time, and will end a second before midnight late on the 5th local time. You have no problem there. The problem is the loop. You start by adding 1 day to the start time but you should start by adding 0 days to the start time.

Comment: Switching to `dayCount++` gives me an array of 8 dates, from November 29 to December 6th

Comment: The loop is giving me all the dates between the start and end dates, in this case the dates are November 30th and December 6th. 
But the start and end dates should November 23 and November 29th. My thinking would be that there is something wrong with the calculation of the start and end dates

Comment: You're not reading what I'm saying. Your start and end dates are correct. The current week (as of this writing) starts today (the 29th) and goes through the 5th. A week starts on Sunday in the USA and Canada, not on Monday.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all dates of this week and next week using following code:-

```
NSArray * allDatesOfThisWeek = [self daysThisWeek];
NSArray * allDatesOfNextWeek = [self daysNextWeek];
```

Following methods are used for calculating dates of this week:-

```
-(NSArray*)daysThisWeek
{
     return  [self daysInWeek:0 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
}

-(NSArray*)daysNextWeek
{
    return  [self daysInWeek:1 fromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
-(NSArray*)daysInWeek:(int)weekOffset fromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //ask for current week
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    comps=[calendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    //create date on week start
    NSDate* weekstart=[calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSDateComponents* moveWeeks=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    moveWeeks.weekOfYear=weekOffset;            
    weekstart=[calendar dateByAddingComponents:moveWeeks toDate:weekstart options:0];


    //add 7 days
    NSMutableArray* week=[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];
    for (int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        NSDateComponents *compsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        compsToAdd.day=i;
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:compsToAdd toDate:weekstart options:0];
        [week addObject:nextDate];

    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:week];
}
```

If you want to get dates of next to next week from today, then pass weekOffset=2 like this:-

```
NSArray * allDatesOfNextToNextWeek = [self daysInWeek:2 fromDate:now];
```

If you want to get dates of previous week from today, then pass weekOffset=-1 like this:-

```
NSArray * allDatesOfPreviousWeek = [self daysInWeek:-1 fromDate:now];
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me.