# How to calculate all Mondays date between two date

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

Having two different entity in coredata with 'ClassDetails' and 'ClassSlots' need all class slot date from 'ClassSlots' entity. Have multiple Class Slots in 'ClassSlots' entity which have class start date and end date in 'ClassDetails' entity. Scenario is like that in time of class addition adding time only sunday-monday-tuesday.. format. Now in time of fetching confused how to fetch those days ( in date format ) between start date and end date of that particular class.

Using this chunk of code but not getting the expected result **( dayId is like this -- 0 for sunday, 1 for monday)**

```
NSLog(@"Start date ==>%@ End date ==>%@ dayId ==>%@",startDate,endDate,dayId);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormator = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormator setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[dateFormator dateFromString:startDate]];

    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setWeekOfYear:[components weekOfYear] + 1];
    [comps setWeekday:[components day]];
    [comps setYear:[components year]];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setFirstWeekday:[dayId intValue]+1];
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSLog(@"date ==> %@",date);
```

Comment: What do you get as the result? And what result do you want?

Comment: all slot date in a class, Ex - The class started from 1st dec, 2015 and end date 31st dec,2015 and it has monday schedule then return all monday ( in date format ) from 1st dec, 2015 to 31st dec,2015

Comment: Try Using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33991698/3908884

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are examining a whole month from first to last day - so you might use the `rangeOfUnit` API of `NSCalendar`.

```
NSDate *aDate; // make this any date in the desired month
NSInteger numberOfDaysInMonth = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
    rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth
    forDate:aDate].length;
```

You can do the rest of the logic yourself if you know what weekday the first day of that month is.

```
NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth;
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
    components:units fromDate:aDate];
comps.day = 1;
NSDate *firstDayInMonth = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
    components: NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:firstDayInMonth];
NSInteger weekdayOfFirstDayInMonth = comps.weekday;
```